# how to create column in by fluent nhibernat that IDENTITY start from 1000 step 1

Tags: c#, sql-server, fluent-nhibernate

I want start identity from 1000 step 1 by `fluent nhibernet` in c# sample under code but these code don't work.

```
 Id(c => c.id).GeneratedBy.Identity("int IDENTITY(1,1000)");
```

Comment: What does "don't work" mean? For an `IDENTITY` property (in T-SQL) the *first* value is the  is the seed and the second the increment; it seems like you simply have the numbers the wrong way round (your seed starts at 1, and increments by 1,000).

Comment: hi my friend... error in fluent hibernate. but i dont know!...